# Mapbox and Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox

please can somebody tell me how I can import a mapbox design into Unity? Probably quite simple I know but I have only just started learning Unity and I'd like to experiment a bit with 3D maps.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a custom map style in the Mapbox Unity SDK just do the following.

- Go to your Mapbox Studio account and click on the **Styles** section
- Open up the additional option of the style you'd like to use and copy the **Style URL** shown
- In Unity go to your **ImageFactory** and change the *Map Type* *Custom*
- Paste the Style URL you had copied into the *Id* field.

After that when you run your scene you should see your custom style used.

Answer (score 0):

go to mapbox.com and download the unity SDK then open unity and go to assests- import pacakege-custom package then choose the mapbox SDK